# PHPBB Seo - URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, phpbb3

I have a problem with the url Rewriting in phpbb. I install the ultimate phpbb Seo for the PHPBB3 and active the Rewrite in advanced mode (First I test in mixed mode). But when I going to cache the url, this one doesn't work, I send the form but the url is not cached.

**The phpbb_cache.php file:**

```
<?php
/**
* phpBB_SEO Class
* www.phpBB-SEO.com
* @package Advanced phpBB3 SEO mod Rewrite
*/
if (!defined('IN_PHPBB')) {
    exit;
}
$this->cache_config['settings'] = array ( 'url_rewrite' => true, 'modrtype' => 3, 'sql_rewrite' => true, 'profile_inj' => false, 'profile_vfolder' => false, 'profile_noids' => false, 'rewrite_usermsg' => true, 'rewrite_files' => false, 'rem_sid' => true, 'rem_hilit' => true, 'rem_small_words' => false, 'virtual_folder' => true, 'cache_layer' => true, 'rem_ids' => true, 'copyrights' => array ( 'img' => true, 'txt' => '', 'title' => '', ), );
$this->cache_config['forum'] = array ( );
?>
```

The permission to the cache (phpbb_seo) folder is 777.

I install in my localhost the premod, this is working fine, but I have one forum in production environment that I need to install only the module.

Thanks!

Comment: To get any useful information you will need to give us more information than this. All i can help you with from what has been given is to ensure that you actually have mod-rewrite enabled on the production server. The last part of your question also makes no sense.

Comment: please show part of your code or your previous attempt to give better help...

Comment: I get the code of php_cache.php file, which is generated when is configurated the phpbb_seo! I saw the server config and the mod_rewrite is enabled.